# Each cant run twice?

Tags: handlebars.js, each

This is somehow a simple issue with handlebars where my TDs are not being rendered.

My Handlebar:

```
<table class="defaultTable" style="width:90mm;">
   <colgroup>
      {{#each cols}}
         <col style="width:{{this.width}}mm;">
      {{/each}}
   </colgroup>
   <tbody>
      {{#each rows}}
         <tr>
            {{#each cols}}
               <td>{{this.content}}</td>
            {{/each}}
         </tr>
      {{/each}}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

My Data:

```
cols = [{
    width: 45,
    content: ''
},{
    width: 45,
    content: ''
}];

Rows = [{},{}];
```

My Output

```
<table class="defaultTable" style="width:90mm;">
   <colgroup>
         <col style="width:45;">
         <col style="width:45;">
   </colgroup>
   <tbody>
         <tr>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Why are the tds not being rendered? Did I miss something regarding how the each loop should work?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to step up a context level when you are inside the `{{#each}}` block. See: http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths. Also, make sure you are consistent with how you name `rows` - either capitalize the first character always or never.

Answer (score 0):

I was out of the context block indeed as the comment stated. It was searching for cols inside the rows object. Will post the fix so other ppl with the same issue can see, hope it helps someone.

```
 <tbody>
      {{#each rows}}
         <tr>
            {{#each ../cols}}
               <td>{{this.content}}</td>
            {{/each}}
         </tr>
      {{/each}}
   </tbody>
```

The `../` on the cols solved it.